# Is it possible to set different options for time machine depending on the destination drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine

I have a local spinning drive where i'd like to keep a 1:1 copy of my macbook hdd but i also have a networked time machine with less space where i'd like to skip archiving some "less important" files i.e. developing VMs images.

Is it possible to configure time machine so that the skipped folders are different depending on destination drive?